# Clearfix: Height 1%

Tags: css, clearfix

In the premium templates on ThemeForest, I see that many templates adopt this method to clearfix:

```
.clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

And add the class clearfix to various elements.

Why height 1%? Is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the height explicitly is the safest (read not the cleanest) way to clear floats. In the themes, the actual clearfix implementation would use :after pseudo selector to clear floats. However the :after property is not supported in IE6/7. Thus, height: 1% is specified. Which works in IE6/7.

Source http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/clearfix-ie

Answer (score 1):

Your theme includes that class for compaitibility with Internet Explorer, which is a good thing.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

https://perishablepress.com/lessons-learned-concerning-the-clearfix-css-hack/

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170)